# Autoit: find text starting with @*****

Tags: find, autoit, scraper

I'm trying to make a IE scraper that will find all logins on webpage starting with @****** for example

@Daley

@DancingDalek

@CrazyLeon

I'm newbie in AutoIt and tried to search similar question but couldn't find one.

Comment: Also I want to save all of these usernames to array/file

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found a solution. I've discovered that all usernames are placed in attributes too

```
<div data-login="username">@username</div>
```

So I've tried this code and it worked perfectly:

```
$tags = $oIE.document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
For $tag in $tags
    $class_value = $tag.GetAttribute("data-login")
    MsgBox(1, "",$class_value)
Next
```